# Create External Table atop pre-partitioned data

Tags: hive

I have data that looks like this:

```
/user/me/output/
  key1/
    part_00000
    part_00001
  key2/
    part_00000
    part_00001
  key3/
    part_00000
    part_00001
```

The data is pre-partitioned by "key_", and the "part_*" files contains my data in the form "a,b,key_".  I create an external table:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tester (
  a STRING,
  b INT
)
PARTITIONED BY (key STRING)
ROW FORMAT 
DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/user/me/output/';
```

But a SELECT * gives no output.  How can I create an external table that will read in this partitioned data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to change your directory structure to make sure that hive reads the folders. It should be something like this.

```
/user/me/output/
  key=key1/
    part_00000
    part_00001
  key=key2/
    part_00000
    part_00001
  key=key3/
    part_00000
    part_00001
```

Once this is done you can create a table on top of this using the query you mentioned.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tester (
  a STRING,
  b INT
)
PARTITIONED BY (key STRING)
ROW FORMAT 
DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/user/me/output/';
```

You will also have to explicitly add the partitions or do a msck repair on the table to load the partitions with hive metadata. Any of these would do:

```
msck repair table tester;
```

OR

```
Alter table tester ADD PARTITION (key = 'key1');
Alter table tester ADD PARTITION (key = 'key2');
Alter table tester ADD PARTITION (key = 'key3');
```

Once you have done this, queries would return the output as present in your folders.